# AttributeError: image_converter instance has no attribute

Tags: python, ros

I need to use an RGB image from image Callback as well as a depth image from depth Callback. I am using ROS. I have declared global variables. In one case if I call my function `abc()` from RGB Callback I am getting this error:

> 'AttributeError: image_converter instance has no attribute `cv_image`

although the image in the `opencv` window is shown. And if instead I use call the `abc()` function in the depth Callback the image is shown properly without any error. My question is why?

```
class image_converter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.pose_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/depth/image_rect_raw",Image,self.depthcallback)
        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/color/image_raw",Image,self.rgbcallback)
        self.count = 0
        self.flag = False
        print(str(self.flag)+"  "+str(self.count))

    def rgbcallback(self,data):
        try:
            self.cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data,"bgr8")
        except:
            print(e)
        # self.ptcldgen()

    def depthcallback(self,data):
        try:
            self.cv_depth = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data,"16UC1")
        except:
            print(e)
        self.ptcldgen()

    def ptcldgen(self):
        cv2.imshow("image",self.cv_image)
        cv2.waitKey(3)

def main(args):
    ic = image_converter()
    rospy.init_node("image_converter",anonymous=True)
    try:
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("shut")
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the attribute `cv_image` could not yet be available at calling using it in `ptcldgen`.

`cv_image` is only set in `rgbcallback` but also used in `depthcallback`. If `depthcallback` gets called before `rgbcallback` was called, the attribute simply does not exist (yet). The result is an [Attribute Error](http://cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/1213/pylearn/final_results/encyclopedia/attributeError.html).

To solve your problem you need to initialize the attribute at initializing your class `__init__`, for example by setting it to none like `self.cv_image = None`.